# Parsing nested JSON with Haskell and Aeson

Tags: haskell, json

I'm trying to reduce nested JSON data using Haskell and Aeson without creating data/record types.
The following code works, but seems ugly and unreadable.
Any advice on cleaning this up would be great.

Thank you

```
import GHC.Exts
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M

testVal :: Value
testVal = Object $ fromList [
  ("items", Array $ fromList [ 
    (Object $ fromList [
      ("entity", (Object $ fromList [ 
        ("uuid", String "needed-value1")]))]),
    (Object $ fromList [
      ("entity", (Object $ fromList [ 
        ("uuid", String "needed-value2")]))])
    ])]

getItems :: Value -> Value
getItems (Object o) = fromJust $ M.lookup "items" o

getEntities :: Value -> Value
getEntities (Array a) = Array $ fmap (\(Object o) -> fromJust $ M.lookup "entity" o) a

getUuids :: Value -> Value
getUuids (Array a) = Array $ fmap (\(Object o) -> fromJust $ M.lookup "uuid" o) a

getTexts :: Value -> [Text]
getTexts (Array a) = toList $ fmap (\(String s) -> s) a


someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
  let items = getItems testVal
      entities = getEntities items
      uuids = getUuids entities
      texts = getTexts uuids
  print texts
```

output:

```
["needed-value1","needed-value2"]
```

Comment: You should really use an algebraic data type to implement your JSON interface. Then you can automatically derive `FromJSON` instances. This will make your code way cleaner.
Could you also provide a sample JSON string that you want to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strongly consider @Erich's advice and define datatypes but it is possible to write quick and dirty queris without them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}                                                                    
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Aeson (Value, Result(..), decode, withObject, (.:))
import Data.Aeson.Types (parse)
import Data.Aeson.QQ.Simple
import Control.Monad ((>=>))


testVal :: Value
testVal = [aesonQQ|
  {"items": [
    {"entity": {"uuid": "needed-value1"}},
    {"entity": {"uuid": "needed-value2"}}
  ]}
|]

getUuids :: Value -> Result [Text]
getUuids = parse $ withObject ""
  $ (.: "items") >=> mapM ((.: "entity") >=> (.: "uuid"))


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ getUuids testVal
  print $ getUuids <$> decode "{}"
  print $ getUuids <$> decode "{"
```

Another option is to use [lens-aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson) package:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens (values, key, _String)

-- [...]

main :: IO ()
main = print
  $ testVal ^.. key "items" . values . key "entity" . key "uuid" . _String
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use an algebraic data type to implement your JSON interface. You can even automatically derive `FromJSON` instances with `DeriveGeneric` GHC extension, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)

data Query = Query { items :: [Entity] }
             deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Query -- automatically derived instance by DeriveGeneric

data Entity = Entity { uuid :: String }
              deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Entity where
    parseJSON = withObject "Entity" $ \v -> do
        -- as your json data is additionally nested with an entity object
        -- extract the entity object first
        obj <- v .: "entity"
        -- then extract the uuid field from the entity object
        uid <- obj .: "uuid"
        return $ Entity uid

testVal :: ByteString
testVal = "{\"items\": [{\"entity\": {\"uuid\": \"needed-value1\"}}, {\"entity\": {\"uuid\": \"needed-value2\"}}]}"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let mayQuery = decode testVal
    case mayQuery of
        Just query -> print $ map uuid $ items query
        Nothing -> putStrLn "JSON parsing error"
```

I transformed your sample `Value` into a JSON string, to make the parsing clearer.

The `FromJSON` instance for `Query` is automatically derived, if you want to write it by hand, you can do this in analogy to the `FromJSON` instance of `Entity`.

This way of parsing your JSON data is very scalable, as you can easily add new fields to your data types, without complicating your code.